# Automatic resizing of Swing components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

When I compile and run my program I would like to be able to re-size it and keep the components with the same scale factor. This would mean that when the frame is expanded the components will also expand, keeping the size and the spacing scale as the original was.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ResizeTst
{
JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("This is my title");

JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

//Components
JButton CompAth = new JButton();
JButton ViewAth = new JButton();
JButton UpdateRD = new JButton();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String []fontFamilies = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
Font FontT5 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 50);
///////////

public void runGUI()
{
    myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756);
    myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

    createFirstPanel();

    myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

    myMainWindow.setVisible(true); 
}

public void createFirstPanel()
{
    firstPanel.setLayout(null);

    CompAth.setLocation(500,250);
    CompAth.setSize(320,300);
    CompAth.setText("<html><CENTER>Compare<br>Athletes</CENTER></html>");
    CompAth.setFont(FontT5);
    firstPanel.add(CompAth);

    ViewAth.setLocation(100,250);
    ViewAth.setSize(320,300);
    ViewAth.setText("<html><CENTER>View<br>Athletes</CENTER></html>");
    ViewAth.setFont(FontT5);
    firstPanel.add(ViewAth);

    UpdateRD.setLocation(900,250);
    UpdateRD.setSize(320,300);
    UpdateRD.setText("<html><CENTER>Update<br>Running<br>Details</CENTER></html>");
    UpdateRD.setFont(FontT5);
    firstPanel.add(UpdateRD);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ResizeTst rt = new ResizeTst();
    rt.runGUI();
}
}
```

So that if I implemented this code it would allow me to run it on any system in full size automatically, without the size of the components changing in scale factor to what they were originally. Allowing for my program to run without it looking bad on larger or smaller screens in full screen.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ResizeTst
{
JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("This is my title");

JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

//Components
JButton CompAth = new JButton();
JButton ViewAth = new JButton();
JButton UpdateRD = new JButton();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String []fontFamilies = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
Font FontT5 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 50);
///////////
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

public void runGUI()
{
    myMainWindow.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    myMainWindow.setSize(screenSize);
    myMainWindow.setVisible(true);    
    myMainWindow.setResizable(true);
    myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

    createFirstPanel();

    myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

    myMainWindow.setVisible(true); 
}
```

I have been told I should use a layout on the panel which would allow me to do this, but I am unaware of which layout to use and how to apply it to this program correctly. Any solutions or suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.  3) Which of those two identically named classes should we be looking at? 4) `new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 50);` for compile time checking, use `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50);`

Comment: 1) I will use this in the Java nomenclature in future. 2) I would have but it won't let me add images till I have 10 reputation. 3) They are the same class but the second one has a new global varible anf an edited runGUI() method to show the code which is the new code for automatically going to full screen. 4) Okay

Comment: 1) My usual reply to that is *"No worries, I might **look at the problem in future**"* The time to do it is ***now!*** 2) You cannot embed images, but upload them to an image share site and link to them. You can always create ASCII art. 3) I don't understand why it is included, I used the first class.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I would appreciate your expertise for help on another question, [Resizing JFrame in one dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133683/resizing-jframe-in-one-dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with something along these lines.  It uses a `GridLayout` that will stretch components to size.  The buttons are made a little larger using `setMargin(Insets)`. The font size is reduced for the screenshot, adjust all numbers to need.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ResizeTst {

    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("This is my title");
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();

//Components
    JButton compAth = new JButton();
    JButton viewAth = new JButton();
    JButton updateRD = new JButton();
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    String[] fontFamilies = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    Font fontT5 = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 25);
///////////

    public void runGUI() {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756); // don't guess the size (1)
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        createFirstPanel();
        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);
        myMainWindow.pack(); // 1) Make it mininum size needed
        myMainWindow.setMinimumSize(myMainWindow.getSize());
        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createFirstPanel() {
        //firstPanel.setLayout(null);
        firstPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0,50,50));
        firstPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50,50,50,50));
        Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20);

        compAth.setText("<html><CENTER>Compare<br>Athletes</CENTER></html>");
        compAth.setMargin(buttonMargin);
        compAth.setFont(fontT5);
        firstPanel.add(compAth);

        viewAth.setMargin(buttonMargin);
        viewAth.setText("<html><CENTER>View<br>Athletes</CENTER></html>");
        viewAth.setFont(fontT5);
        firstPanel.add(viewAth);

        updateRD.setMargin(buttonMargin);
        updateRD.setText("<html><CENTER>Update<br>Running<br>Details</CENTER></html>");
        updateRD.setFont(fontT5);
        firstPanel.add(updateRD);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // should be on the EDT!
        ResizeTst rt = new ResizeTst();
        rt.runGUI();
    }
}
```